# Read user input and modify an array using EOF within a function in C?

Tags: c, arrays, parameters, scanf, eof

I trying to use EOF for user input in a function and also modify the array accordingly, so in the main function it'll be that value.  I've tried searching with Google and reading over people's answers, but I still can't get it to work..

```
void Get_Data(double data[], double original[], int length)
{
    int count = 0;
    double value = 0;
    printf("Enter data and Ctrl + D when you're done(Ctrl + Z for Windows): \n");

    while (scanf("%f", &value) != EOF)
    {
        data[count] = value;
        original[count] = data[count];
        count++;
    }
    printf("%f\n", data[1]);
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    double sum, original[4] = {0}, datas[4] = {0};
    Get_Data(datas, original, 4); // I'm just trying to get this to work

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I read about passing by reference in C using * in the parameters, but I didn't get the right result.

Comment: First: What is an 'Fn' ? Second: What is the result you expect and what is the result you get. Some more details are helpfull

Comment: Not only do you need to use `"%lf"` as the format specifier to read a `double` value, you also need to check that you got `1` back from `scanf()`; you will get 0 (which is not the same as EOF) if there's a non-numeric, non-space character in the input, and your program could run a while before it crashes.  You should also ensure you don't go beyond the number of entries in `length` inside the function — writing out of the bounds of an array is a bad case of 'undefined behaviour'.

Answer (score 2):

To scan a `double` value, you need to use `%lf` format specifier.

From `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.2,

> *`l (ell)`*
>  Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, `X`, or `n` conversion specifier applies
>   to an argument with type pointer to `long int` or `unsigned long
>   int`; that a following `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, or `G` conversion specifier applies to
>   an argument with type pointer to `double`; [....]

That said,

1. as you're rightly passing the `length`, make use of it inside your function to limit the `count` (index) to avoid overrunning the allocated memory.
2. You should also check for the success of `scanf()` (by checking the returned value against the number of items *supposed* to be scanned). Only checking aginst `EOF` foes not suffice, `scanf()` can also return 0 in case of matching failure which needs to be handled, too.

Comment: Yes — but that's not the only problem in the code shown in the question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Are you pointing out the most-obvious success check on the `scanf()` return or something else that I'm missing?

Comment: Since you updated your answer to mention `length` (compared with the first version I saw — but you obviously changed it within the 5-minute window), then yes, the main other problem is checking `!= EOF` vs `== 1`.  I find that one disadvantage of me using 'HTTPS Everywhere' is that the auto-updating on SO doesn't work very much any more; I have to refresh to see changes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Right. Let me add that bit of info also.

Answer (score 1):

Change `while (scanf("%f", &value) != EOF)` to `while (scanf("%lf", &value) == 1)`.

Firstly, to check whether a input process succeeds, you shouldn't use `scanf("...", ...) != EOF`. Think about it: What if a user inputs a character? Then `scanf()` will return 0 after having a matching failure, and `0 != EOF`.

Secondly, to scan a variable has the type of `double`, you have to use a `"%lf"`. You may ask: Why? I can print both `float` and `double` by using a `"%f"`!

Well, that is because usually `sizeof (float) != sizeof (double)`. Let's say `sizeof (float) == 4` and `sizeof (double) == 8`:

- In a `scanf()` statement, the program have to know the length of memory block to write to. If there is a `"%f"`, and `0x12345678` is passed as the corresponding address, `0x12345678` to `0x1234567C` are filled, while when there is a `"%lf"`, and `0x12345678` is passed as the address, memory from `0x12345678` to `0x12345680` are filled.
- Since `printf()` has variadic parameters, `float` variables are implicitly converted to `double`, then passed. It's obvious that convert a `float` to `double` doesn't cause any lost of information, so everything is  OK.

To sum up, the point is that `float`s are automatically promoted to `double`s, but `float *`s are not converted to `double *`.